Manual fix to merge conflict on csproj file vanishes after accept merge
Background
I have two branches that both branched of from my dev trunk. We are currently still somewhat on a prototype so we are doing manual versioning of a nuget package that's included in the application and published when the pipeline has run a build (after PR approval).
So I have:

dev - version 1.0.11
BranchA - version 1.0.12 - branched from dev 1.0.11
BranchB - version 1.0.13 - branched from dev 1.0.11

It was two very different implementations that were committed and pushed with a PR for each.
What I run into
I have a merge conflict on the PR of BranchA because the PR for BranchB was completed earlier.
It's the difference between:
<Version>1.0.12</Version>

and
<Version>1.0.13</Version>

Where it should become 1.0.13.
What I did
If I merge BranchA and BranchB together on my local I indeed get the same conflict as with the PR. I select the correct version 1.0.13 and click Accept Merge.
The problem
After clicking Accept Merge the merge conflict is resolved, but there is also no change to the csproj file.
That means I have nothing to commit, meaning I can't update my PR and get it completed.

Why does my change to my csproj file disappear and how can I prevent it?

PS: I have requested installation of Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension, but that needs to go through bureaucracy and I am trying to speed up my change by fixing it manually. (I should be able to do that anyway)

It's the weirdest thing, a team mate did the same action, he was able to push the change so the PR is through. Looks to be some kind of [git] hiccup.

I am providing a bit manual flow. Check if it works for you.
You can merge the PR from Branch B first into dev branch.
Now on your local, -> checkout Branch A -> Merge remote dev branch into Branch A -> Resolve the conflicts locallly and commit -> Raise PR from Branch A to dev.

I can reproduce the same issue on my side. Checking the response of REST API Pull Requests - Get Pull Request can help us understand the reason of the conflict.

When committing in BranchA and creating a PRA:


lastMergeTargetCommit ID is the latest commit id in dev.
mergeBaseCommit ID is the same as lastMergeTargetCommit ID


When committing in BranchB and creating PRB:


lastMergeTargetCommit ID is the latest commit id in dev.
mergeBaseCommit ID is the same as lastMergeTargetCommit ID.


After merging BranchB into dev:


The lastMergeTargetCommit ID of PRA will change to lastMergeCommit of PRB, which is the id of commit from BranchB to dev.

The mergeBaseCommit ID of PRA isn't changed.
For PRA, lastMergeTargetCommit and mergeBaseCommit are no longer consistent, which means that target branch and source branch both change and causes conflicts.


